# SSRS Delete Users Via TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, ssrs

We want to remove SSRS users via TSQL rather than manually deleting their permissons via the reporting services admin page.
Testing on SQL 2017 dev edition

We have a script that does run and does remove data from tables, reassigns permissions.

```
USE ReportServer$RSWEB

DECLARE @ownerid uniqueidentifier; SET @ownerid = (SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE UserName = 'Old.User')
DECLARE @newownerid uniqueidentifier; SET @newownerid = (SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE UserName = 'ssrs_admin')
BEGIN TRAN

  UPDATE Subscriptions SET ModifiedByID = @newownerid WHERE ModifiedByID = @ownerid
  UPDATE Subscriptions SET OwnerID = @newownerid WHERE OwnerID = @ownerid
  UPDATE Schedule SET CreatedById = @newownerid WHERE CreatedById = @ownerid 
  UPDATE Catalog SET ModifiedByID = @newownerid WHERE ModifiedByID = @ownerid
  UPDATE Catalog SET CreatedById = @newownerid WHERE CreatedByID = @ownerid
  DELETE FROM PolicyUserRole WHERE UserID = @ownerid
  DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserID = @ownerid

COMMIT
```

If I run this and then look in the site settings web page for SSRS the user account is still visible .If I make a change to another user, add more permissions for example, the account we have manually removed is added back in.

I have searched through the tables for the username or unique id for the account post deletion and I cannot see it. Ran profiler (test system) to try and see what is happening but again, cannot see how this gets re created.

Does anyone have any advice, I know this isn't best practice and I assume not recommended by MS.

Comment: I can't change the users in the web folders from sql server. You have to use powershell against SSRS web service. Take a look at this:
https://www.sqlshack.com/managing-ssrs-security-using-powershell-automation-scripts/

Comment: thanks for this mate, will check it out and test.